# how to combine everything in a pandas dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with information, where the rows are not related to eachother:

```
   Fruits  Vegetables  Protein
1  Apple   Spinach     Beef
2  Banana  Cucumber    Chicken
3  Pear    Carrot      Pork
```

I essentially just want to create a pandas series with all of that information, I want it to look like this:

```
   All Foods
1  Apple 
2  Banana   
3  Pear
4  Spinach
5  Cucumber 
6  Carrot
7  Beef
8  Chicken
9  Pork
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: Is the index important? Normally it'd start at 0.

Comment: Related; [python pandas flatten a dataframe to a list](/q/25440008/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

Dump into numpy and create a new dataframe:

```py
out = df.to_numpy().ravel(order='F')
pd.DataFrame({'All Foods' : out})
  All Foods
0     Apple
1    Banana
2      Pear
3   Spinach
4  Cucumber
5    Carrot
6      Beef
7   Chicken
8      Pork
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `pd.concat` them together (and reset the index).

```
all_foods = pd.concat([foods[col] for col in foods.columns])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the dataframe to get the values and then create a df/series:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['Apple','Banana', 'Pear'], 'Vegetables':['Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cucumber'], 'Protein':['Beef', 'Chicken', 'Pork']})

pd.DataFrame({'All Foods' : df.unstack().values})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
import pandas as pd

# Loading file with fruits, vegetables and protein
dataset = pd.read_csv('/fruit.csv')

# This is where you should apply your code
# Unpivoting (creating one column out of 3 columns)
df_unpivot = pd.melt(dataset, value_vars=['Fruits', 'Vegetables', 'Protein'])
# Renaming column from value to All Foods
df_finalized = df_unpivot.rename(columns={'value': 'All Foods'})
# Printing out "All Foods" column
print(df_finalized["All Foods"])
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why use this instead of, say [My Work's answer](/a/74367723/4518341), which does essentially the same thing?